# Align dynamically loaded user controls horizontally inside HTML table cell

Tags: asp.net, html, user-controls, web-user-controls

I have a html table which has a  element with runat=server. I am loading some user controls inside it from code behind.

```
    <td id ="ModuleGridHolder" runat="server" rowspan="3">            
    </td>
```

This is the user control HTML

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ModuleGrid.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="RadTreeListTest.Controls.ModuleGrid" %>

    <table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="width:100%;">

    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvSectionCells" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns= "true">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#9999FF" />
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvSectionTotalCells" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#9999FF" />
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
          <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sumRow" HeaderText="" />                                      
            </Columns>              
        </asp:GridView>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is the simplyfied version of the code which is rendering several user controls inside it.

```
  foreach loop
  {
      ModuleGrid mg = (ModuleGrid)LoadControl("ModuleGrid.ascx");
      ModuleGridHolder.Controls.Add(mg);
  }
```

The problem is all the rendered controls are loading vertically I.E. on top of each other. How do I align them horizontally inside the  cell?

I have tried using float:left but it is not working?

Comment: Can you add the code that is outputted into the browser?

Comment: @Manas Saha: What is output/html of `ModuleGrid.ascx`?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with the HTML of the user control.

Comment: I think it is a more HTML/CSS related problem.

Comment: I don't think that you should use tables this way. A more current way is to use divs and spans. However your usercontrol has a line at the top that says `<table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="width:100%;">` width:100% will make this controls table to fill the whole width and no space will be left for another control on its side. If you want to stick with the nested table design maybe you should make all of the dynamically loaded controls cells into a table with one row.

Comment: @ManasSaha A note, neither `cellpadding` nor `cellspacing` uses px, their value is just plain 0. Like so: `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">`. This does not solve the problem at hand though. But we still need to see the outputted code, not the ASP code itself. What does the browser see? Also, what CSS is applied? As noted above by @mo, this has not to do with the ASP but the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CssClass parameter in your code and apply to each control. This way you can centrally style each dynamic control that you load on the page:

```
foreach loop
{
    ModuleGrid mg = (ModuleGrid)LoadControl("ModuleGrid.ascx");
    mg.CssClass = "myStyle";
    ModuleGridHolder.Controls.Add(mg);
}
```

Once the controls are using your stylesheet class, link a stylesheet to your aspx page and use something like this:

```
.myStyle
{
   float: left;
   width: 100px;
}
```

If you're already doing something similar to this, I'd suggest assigning a fixed width (or percentage) to each control to see if that gets them to float to the left of each other, it could be that without a width specified the controls are just using 100% width and causing subsequent controls to "stack" vertically.

Overall I'd avoid using a table for this entirely and just stick to DIV tags. I find them much easier to position than having to mess around with tables, columns and rows.